# Kotlin/Android Collectors/ Observers not finding any changes outside the class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Here is my repo class to ensure the state of my location is changed

```
@Singleton
class LocationRepository @Inject constructor(){

    private val _locationData = MutableStateFlow<Location?>(null)
    val locationData: StateFlow<Location?>  = _locationData.asStateFlow()


    init {

    }

    fun updateLocation(location: Location) {
        _locationData.update {
        location
        }
        locationData.value?.let { logthis(it) }

    }

}


fun logthis(location: Location)
{

    Log.i("This works", location.toString())

}
```

The class logs all work but anywhere else for example the viewmodel

```
 @HiltViewModel
class myViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val mainRepository: Repository,
    private val commonUtils: AppUtils,
): ViewModel()
{
    @Inject
   lateinit var locationRepository: LocationRepository
```

or my composable

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen(
 viewModel = myViewModel = hiltViewModel()
)

{ //a bunch of other code here
val location = viewModel.locationRepository.locationData
   val locationData by location.collectAsState(null)

    LaunchedEffect(locationData){
        Log.i("Doesn't work", locationData.toString())

    }

    LaunchedEffect(locationRepository){
        locationRepository.locationData.collect{
            Log.i("Also doesnt work", it.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

I expected to see some logs and fire some additional operations and return a success message but i never even get to that point.

I used the repo as a Singleton to ensure its the only instance of the class running but clearly something is wrong because that hasn't worked as well

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your class as `Singleton`:

```
@Singleton
class LocationRepository @Inject constructor(){

    private val _locationData = MutableStateFlow<Location?>(null)
    val locationData: StateFlow<Location?>  = _locationData.asStateFlow()
```

But it seems that it is not singleton because every object has its own value for `locationData`.

Your problem is caused by using different objects of `LocationRepository`.

In other words **you are creating the object yourself instead of using Dependency Injection** (Hilt or Dagger) So your object is **not** singleton.

In viewmodel use below code:

```
@Inject
lateinit var locationRepository: LocationRepository// Here DI injects Singleton object
```

**instead** **of** creating object like this:

```
val locationRepository = LocationRepository() // Do NOT create object yourself
```

Also in Composable function do **not** use this code:

```
locationRepository: LocationRepository = remember {
        LocationRepository() // Do NOT create object yourself
)
```

**replace it with this:**

```
val locationRepository = viewmodel.locationRepository
val locationData by locationRepository.locationData.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but this still is yet to work
viewModel now is 

 @Inject
   lateinit var locationRepository: LocationRepository
and my composable also changed to watch from the view model and even logging every 5 secs with a launched effect still produces null but in the repo i get valid locations every 5 seconds

Comment: I,ve edited the post to my current code except the logging every 5 sec part

Comment: @NomadTre replace `location.collectAsState` with `location.collectAsStateWithLifecycle`